# Send meeting notification from Dynamics CRM workflow

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I create a workflow that sends notification email, which is triggered by "Appointment created" event.

I want it to send meeting invitation (which could be accepted/rejected in Outlook), not the regular email, what is the trick here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mail message as a custom workflow activity and send it via SMTP :

- Develop a custom workflow activity with appropriate input parameters (start time, end time, smtp server name etc.) which you can configure to map to CRM entity fields.
- In your C# code, you will need to generate a iCal event. You could do this by reading and understanding the iCal spec and generating a string manually in the correct format [like this](http://sharepoint-tamizha.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/send-event-as-email-in-c.html), or just use a library like the the [DDay.iCal](http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.iCal/) library. Note,  if you use this library, you will either need to deploy this dll in the GAC, or merge it using ILMerge when you build the workflow activity.
- Convert the iCal object back to a string.
- Send the iCal as an email via smtp (note, smtp likely won't work from CRM online sandbox, only on premise) but change the content type of the MailMessage to "text/calendar"
- Message should arrive as an acceptable calendar in Outlook which will display based on how you have configured the iCal event properties.
- Configure the workflow activity against the appropriate entity (Appointment / Service activity).

Sample approach in code below - note, not production ready. You need to understand the iCal properties you want to set and slot this into the boilerplate workflow activity code accordingly.

```
    // 3rd party libraries to reference
    using DDay.iCal;
    using DDay.iCal.Serialization.iCalendar;
    ...
    ...
    // Create the iCal
    IICalendar iCal = new iCalendar();
    iCal.Method = "Request";
    ...
    ...
    IEvent evt = iCal.Create<Event>();
    evt.Summary = summary;
    evt.Start = new iCalDateTime(eventstartDt).SetTimeZone(local);
    evt.End = new iCalDateTime(eventendDt).SetTimeZone(local);
    var serializer = new iCalendarSerializer(iCal);
    var iCalString = serializer.SerializeToString(iCal);
    ...
    ...
    var mailMessage = new MailMessage
    {
       Subject = Summary.Get(_executionContext),
       From = new MailAddress(FromEmailAddress.Get(_executionContext))
    };

    // Create the Alternate view object with Calendar MIME type
    var ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");
    if (ct.Parameters != null) ct.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");

    //Provide the framed string here
    AlternateView avCal = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(iCalString, ct);
    mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(avCal);

    // Send email
    try
    {
       smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       // Log it.
    }
```